# Maximum value from a difference of two functions

Tags: python-2.7

I have two functions:

Sales for 2015: `pcity15 = iowa1q15.groupby('City').apply(lambda x :x['sales'].sum())`

Sales for 2016: `pcity16 = iowa1q16.groupby('City').apply(lambda x :x['sales'].sum())`

The above two functions are from two different dataframes.

To find out the difference between the sales of different cities, I'm simply subtracting the functions

`(pcity16 - pcity15)`

I want to find out the city which has the maximum growth from 2015 to 2016.

Can anyone help?

Comment: what are the values in your variables? can you uplead sample data and code?

Comment: If the variables `pcity16` and `pcity15` are `pd.Series` you can use `idxmax` method of the series